# Regarding Image mouse over effect in asp.net

Tags: css

I'm a software developer and I'm stuck with one problem.

Problem: Whenever I'm moving my mouse over my image it shows mouse over effect, but my problem is I want this effect to persist after mouse moving away also.

Comment: Mouse moving outside the `:hover` element?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question further? Can you post the sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Seems hover event should be replaced by **mouseover** which is sent to an element when the mouse pointer enters the element.